# Chart.js undefined variable in view

Tags: javascript, laravel, charts

I want to crate a graph using chart.js and show it in my view. But after parsing the data to the view, it always come with undefined variable (in my case, bulan and pendapatan is undefined).

This is my controller to parse the data

```
$query = DB::table("transaksipenjualan")->select(DB::raw('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM tanggaltransaksi) AS Bulan, SUM(total) as Pendapatan'))
        ->where('tanggalTransaksi', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->tahun.'%')
        ->groupBy(DB::raw('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM tanggaltransaksi)'))
        ->get();

        $count=count($query);
        $label  = [];
        $data   = [];

        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
        {
            $label[$i]  = $query[$i]->Bulan;
            $data[$i]   = $query[$i]->Pendapatan;
        }

        return view('printPreview/pendapatanBulanan',  ['data'=>$query, 'bulan'=>$label, 'pendapatan'=>$data]);
```

And this is my script to get the data

```
 var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
          var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: bulan,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Nilai Pendapatan',
                    data: pendapatan,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```

I don't know very well how to pass the data to a script, so I need some advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `{{ json_encode($php_variable) }}`? For example:

```
 var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
          var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: {{ json_encode($bulan) }},
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Nilai Pendapatan',
                    data: {{ json_encode($pendapatan) }},
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: this is dirty solution, but one of them for sure. Another one is to use a package like [this](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer) and transform PHP vars to JavaScript.

Comment: @nakov I agree, that is a good package. But if the OP only needs those two variables, the Blade syntax might be sufficient.

Comment: I agree, but then again, having JavaScript code in a blade view, it is ugly to me :)